# Busy/loading state in monaco editor

Tags: monaco-editor

In vscode there is a beautiful blue bar moving for showing busy/loading state. Can I enable it in monaco-editor inside browser? Or it is specific to vscode?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is not part of monaco-editor. You have to implement that yourself, for example using a CSS animation.